# center text in select on ios7

Tags: html, select, ios7, center

This code works in ios6 (text aligned centered in selectbox). But in ios7 it is aligned left?

```
select {
    text-align: -webkit-center;
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this to center text in a select on ios7?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `text-align:center` without the `-webkit` vendor. Seems like it isn't supported.

Comment: yes, doesnt work on ios7 nor in ios6. text-align: -webkit-center; works in 6 though

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick on angularjs or using js to map selected value with a text on the div, this solution is full css compliant on angular but need a mapping between select and div:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('selectCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.value = ''; 
}]);
```

```css
.ghostSelect {
  opacity: 0.1;
  /* Should be 0 to avoid the select visibility but not visibility:hidden*/
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
.select {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-guide-concepts-1-production</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-app ng-controller="selectCtrl">
    <div class=select>
      <select ng-model="value" class="ghostSelect">
        <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
      <div>{{value}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this could be useful for someone as it took me one day to find this solution on phonegap.